# Can't assign null value to a double? property in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper and one line causes an error when I try to assign null in ternary operator like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.VatCategoryTaxAmount, 
           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TaxSubtotal != null && 
                                     src.TaxSubtotal.TaxCategory != null 
                                     ? double.Parse(src.TaxSubtotal.TaxCategory.Percent) 
                                     : null));
```

Error:

> Cannot convert anonymous method block to type 'type' because it is not a delegate type

When I use `0` instead of `null`, then it works.

I'm confused because the destination property is of type `double?`. I want to assign to it a null value.

How can I do that?

Comment: In my humble opinion, AutoMapper is the worst library in the .NET ecosystem. Thousands of similar mapping questions on the SO won't let me lie. Just get rid of it and your code will become concise and simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your conditional assignment doesn't return the same type.

```
src.TaxSubtotal.TaxCategory != null ? double.Parse(src.TaxSubtotal.TaxCategory.Percent) : null
```

it returns a `double` if true or `null` if false. Try to cast the true assignment to a nullable.

Comment: it wokrs `(double?)double.Parse(src.TaxSubtotal.TaxCategory.Percent!)` I dont know if there any more elegant solution?

Comment: None that I can think off right now. Nullable double doesn't have a parse method. Think it's as good as it gets.

Comment: Try just `opt.MapFrom(src => src.TaxSubtotal.TaxCategory.Percent)`.